# Split text before @ in email in Django

Tags: python, django, string, split, view

Hi i have a **array** in my **views** such as

```
user_domain_array = ['rohit@ghrix.com','rahul@ghrix.com','rishi@ghrix.com']
```

i need to **remove** the text from each element **before** `@` from all email ids so that i can get the **values** like

```
ghrix.com
```

Please suggest me how can i do this.

Comment: Show us your code and tells where your problem is, we don't write code for you.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
for email in user_domain_array:
    domain = email.split('@', 1)[-1]
```

This splits the string *once* on `@` then takes the last element of the resulting list. This has the advantage that you still get a result even if no at-sign was present in the input string.

Demo:

```
>>> 'rohit@ghrix.com'.split('@', 1)[-1]
'ghrix.com'
>>> 'rohit.ghrix.com'.split('@', 1)[-1]
'rohit.ghrix.com'
```

Comment: @sachitad: Perhaps because I dared answer a question that didn't show enough effort in the eyes of the downvoter?

Comment: Oh, well might be too jealous of your awesome reputation! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> user_domain_array = ['rohit@ghrix.com','rahul@ghrix.com','rishi@ghrix.com']
>>> [domain.split('@')[1] for domain in user_domain_array]
['ghrix.com', 'ghrix.com', 'ghrix.com']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> regex = re.compile("@")
>
> [ i.split(m.group())[1]  for i in user_domain_array  for m in [regex.search(str(i))]  if m]

**It will work in both input condition -:**

1) user_domain_array = ['rohit@ghrix.com','rahul@ghrix.com','rishi@ghrix.com']

2) user_domain_array = ['rohit.ghrix.com','rahul@ghrix.com','ghrix.com']